# How to sync iPhone songs to MacBook Pro?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I synced my Windows iTunes with my iPhone 7 and put a lot of songs on my phone.
Today I got a USB to USB-C hub for my MacBook ( I have a windows PC and a macOS laptop ), and my iPhone appears on iTunes on my macbook.

How can I transfer songs from my macbook to my phone ? Apparently there can be only one " source " computer that can be linked to the iPhone. I only want to add a few songs from 2 different devices, not download my whole library to one single device ( my macbook doesn't have enough space to handle all of this ). How can I do that ?

When I do try to " restore purchases ", it tells my I have to authorise the device through the " Account " menu, which I've already done multiple times.

Anyone went through this ?
Thanks !